# Populate properties from one ontology to another

Tags: ontology, semantic-web, knowledge-graph

I am quite new to Semantic Web and I have a task to model two ontologies. Let's say that ontology A has 3 classes, 4 object properties and 4 datatype properties. Ontology A also includes class instances with all the data. Now, ontology B has identical structure as ontology A, plus a couple of extra datatype properties, but it does not have any instances - it only contains the schema. Let's say that I create ontology B class instance with a certain ID. My question is, how based on that ID (which is identical in ontology A) can I populate or pull all the properties from A to B that are identical in both ontologies?
For example ontology A instance has following properties: ontologyAinstance id:1, name:'instance name', age:'15YO' . How can I pull name and age properties from A to B when I create: ontologyBinstance id:1?

Comment: One ontology can import another ontology. In fact this is indeed the way large ontologies are constructed in practice. As an example, [here](https://github.com/EBISPOT/DUO/blob/master/duo.owl) is a smallish ontology importing  the iao ontology.